# Как на android смартфонах добавляют предустановленные неудаляемые приложения?

Tags: android

Интересует вопрос, как, например, на РСТ смартфоны на Android устанавливают тот же Яндекс и делают его неудаляемым?
Просто устанавливают приложение через adb без активации смартфона?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Файловая система андроида состоит из нескольких логических разделов. Раздел линукс, системный раздел и раздел приложений (в старых ещё раздел данных) и кеш.

Неудаляемые приложения устанавливаются в системный раздел, который перезаписывается полностью при обновлении системы.  В нерутованном смартфоне этот раздел только для чтения.

Answer (score 2):

Добавляют приложение в system/app или в system/priv-app